# Pourquoi inverser l'ordre des mots dans « sans doute n’est-ce plus » ?

Tags: sens, inversion

Le contexte:

> Je reconnais qu’il y a de superbes images et que les moyens techniques
>   sont impressionnants. Mais l’histoire ne vaut pas un clou, hein !
>   C’est gnangnan, édulcoré, sucré à vous donner la nausée. Mais bon, sans  doute **n’est-ce plus** de mon âge !…

Et pourquoi la partie « n’est-ce plus de mon âge » n'est elle pas plutôt écrite « ce n'est plus de mon âge ». C'est à dire, pourquoi inverser l'ordre comme dans une question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certains adverbes, dont *sans doute*, **quand ils sont placés en tête de proposition** entraînent l'inversion du sujet. Le sens de la phrase est exactement le même qu'avec l'ordre normal de la phrase déclarative :

> Mais bon, ce n'est sans doute plus de mon âge !
>   Mais bon, sans doute n’est-ce plus de mon âge !

En général cette inversion est essentiellement du ressort de la langue littéraire mais assez fréquente, même à l'oral, avec *sans doute*, *à peine* et *peut-être*.  Ce n'est pas une question et on ne met pas de point d'interrogation, sauf si on veut vraiment poser une question, comme par exemple :

> - Sans doute voulais-tu dire « gnangnan » ?
> - Tu voulais sans-doute dire « gnangnan » ?

→ dans ces deux phrases ce n'est pas l'ordre des mots qui fait que ce sont des questions mais la présence du point d'interrogation à l'écrit, et l'intonation à l'oral.

Quelques autres adverbes et locutions adverbiales concernés par cette inversion (liste non exhaustive) :
 *ainsi, aussi, aussi bien, à plus forte raison, à peine,  du moins, pour le moins, tout au moins, à tout le moins, tout au plus, encore moins, peut-être*.

À noter que l'inversion se fait uniquement avec un pronom :

> - Nos voisins sont peut-être absents, leurs volets sont fermés.
> - Peut-être nos voisins sont-ils absents, leurs volets sont fermés.

→  pour faire l'inversion on fait la reprise du sujet *voisins* avec le pronom personnel sujet correspondant : *ils*.

Références :
[BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3472), [Le blog de Mamiehou](http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-l-inversion-du-sujet-apres-ainsi-aussi-aussi-bien-a-peine-peut-etre-sans-doute-encore-du-moin-115406144.html), [*N'écris pas comme tu chattes*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=76Z0AwAAQBAJ&pg=PT36&lpg=PT36&dq=inversion%20apr%C3%A8s%20sans-doute&source=bl&ots=UDuV0sR9bx&sig=ct-Y2x-v262Z1BFYV5sV2a4jCXw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6jYqEhsLVAhWqA8AKHSJZCi44ChDoAQhIMAc#v=onepage&q=inversion%20apr%C3%A8s%20sans-doute&f=false) (Jean-Paul JAUNEAU - 2011), [Services Éditions](http://www.servicesdedition.com/fr/langue/difficultes/inversion.html), [Termium plus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9opkVN9D2Afc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parce que *c'est une question* et qui pourrait très bien être suivie d'un point d'interrogation, mais qui est ici suivie d'un point d'exclamation pour des raisons stylistiques et non grammaticales.