# Hyphen attached pronoun "se livrait-il"

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-personnels, inversion

Jules Verne: Les Aventures du capitaine Hatteras.

In first chapter i've encountered sentence:

> Aussi, à bord du Nautilus, ancré non loin, un groupe de matelots **se livrait-il** à mille conjectures sur la destination du Forward.

I can't understand why we need hyphen + pronom here: this is not a question, not imperative, and not a dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It' a grammar rule: in French you have to insert a hyphen between the verb and the subject pronoun when they are inverted, whatever the reason for the inversion. That means we need a hyphen:

- When  asking a question: *Où es-tu ?*
- In incidental clauses: *Je suis dans ma chambre, répondit-elle.*
- And **whenever** a word or a phrase requires the inversion.

*Aussi* placed **at the beginning of a sentence** is a coordinator and marks a consequence or an explanation. In this case, the verb and subject of the sentence it introduces can be reversed.

In the case of *aussi* the inversion is not compulsory (*Aussi un groupe de matelots se livrait ...* would be possible). In some cases the inversion is compulsory, it is the case with *peut-être* (*Peut-être est-elle dans sa chambre*), *encore* (*Encore faudrait-il qu'elle soit arrivée*), *sans doute*, *probablement*, and a few more.

Note that in the imperative there's no subject, just a verb (*Parle !*). I expect you meant the imperative of reflexive verbs, as in *Lave-toi les mains !* where *toi* is the reflexive pronoun.

Comment: I remember being taught in school that _questions_ do not allow inversion of the verb and a non-pronominal subject, requiring instead that the non-pronominal subject remain in preverbal position and then repeated by a resumptive pronoun; e.g., “Depuis quand ton père est-il malade ?”, not “*Depuis quand est ton père malade ?”. This is different from other constructions, where non-pronominal subjects do invert: “Le médecin que connaît l’avocat”, “« Non », répondit Marie”, “Tomba un voile de brume” (poetic). I have only just now learnt that the restriction found in questions also applies to →

Comment: → inversion caused by a sentence-intial adverb like _ainsi_, _aussi_, etc., so that inversion in such cases adds a resumptive pronoun after the verb. I think I would naturally have said, “Peut-être ma mère peut-elle [qqc.]”, but “Aussi un groupe de matelots se livrait-il…” is definitely new to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  [An answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26712/358) about  containing a few links to find out more about this inversion when the sentence begins with an adverb.

Comment: "in French you have to insert a hyphen between the verb and the subject when they are inverted" -> between a verb and a weak pronoun, really, there'd be no hyphen in "blabla, dit Paula", and as you note there's also a hyphen with inverted object pronouns, like in lave-toi

Comment: @Eauquidort Merci ! j'avais oublié un mot. On a beau se relire...